# Filter JSON objects based on condition in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the below JSON response. In Backbone I want to filter some objects(names) from the array

For example - Here i need to loop only 'Jack','Mcd' objects(names. Need to get only Jack and Mcd names from arrary.

Can anyone give me any ideas to implement?

```
resultstest = {
"r": [{
    "IsActive": false,
    "re": {
        "Name": "Depo"            
    },
    "Expire": "Oct8, 2013",
    "Clg": [{
        "Name": "james",
        "Rate": 0.05
    }, {
        "Name": "Jack",
        "Rate": 0.55
   }, {
        "Name": "Ander",
        "Rate": 0.46
   }, {
        "Name": "Mcd",
        "Rate": 0.01,
    }],
},
{
    "IsActive": false,
    "re": {
        "Name": "Depo"
    },
    "Expire": "Oct8, 2013",
    "Clg": [{
        "Name": "james",
        "Rate": 0.05
    }, {
        "Name": "Jack",
        "Rate": 0.55
   }, {
        "Name": "Mcd",
        "Rate": 0.01,
    }],
},
{
    "IsActive": false,
    "re": {
        "Name": "Depo"
    },
    "Expire": "Oct8, 2013",
    "Clg": [{
        "Name": "james",
        "Rate": 0.05
    }, {
        "Name": "Jack",
        "Rate": 0.55
   }, {
        "Name": "Mcd",
        "Rate": 0.01,
    }],
}]
};    

loadjson = function (input) {
        if (_.isArray(input)) {
            var collection = new CompeCollection();
            _.each(input, function (modelData) {
                ....
            });
            return collection;
        }
            };
var tablesResult = loadjson(resultstest.r[0].Clg); // can we filter here like resultstest.r[0].Clg(!="james" && !="Ander")
```

Is there any array method to filter those objects while passing to loadjson function? Any help would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I assume that this isn't your real code is it? `function CompeCollection() { this.add = function() { }; }
function CompeModel() { };`

Comment: yes, It is not real code. I just replicated it. I am just looking for is there any way to filter the object while passing to loadFromJson1 function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter` method of arrays supported in modern browsers. For compatibility of old browsers, you can use `_.filter` (http://underscorejs.org/#filter).

So your code would be like,

```
var tablesResult = loadjson(_.filter(resultstest.r[0].Clg, function(clg) { return (clg.name !="james" && clg.name !="Ander"); }))
```

To DRY your code, you can event create this filter function separately and simple reference it here. Like,

```
var collegeFilter = function(clg) { return (clg.name !="james" && clg.name !="Ander"); }
...
var tablesResult = loadjson(_.filter(resultstest.r[0].Clg, collegeFilter));
```